# Ruby on rails-paperclip do not save to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm a newbies to the rails world . What I'm trying to do is to add the abilities to user to add picture . I did some reaserch and, I found a gem called "paperclip",but after installing. Every time I try to upload a picture, I get "no file selected".

this is my models

```
attr_accessible :description, :image
 validates :description, presence: true
 validates :user_id, presence: true
 belongs_to :user 
 has_attached_file :image , :styles => { :small => "150x150>" }

 validates_attachment :image , :presence => true,
 :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg","image/png","image/gif"] },
 :size => { :in => 0..10.kilobytes }
```

and this is my views

```
<div class="form-inputs">
 <%= f.input :image , label: "upload a picture !! " %>
<%= f.input :description , as: :text ,input_html: { rows:"3"} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step by Step**

Gem

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
```

Terminal

```
$ bundle install
$ rails generate paperclip user image
$ rake db:migrate
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible:image, :description

  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>"}

  validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                            content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'] },
                            size: { less_than: 5.megabytes } # you wanna change that
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Your View is ok, don't forget to `rake db:migrate` and `restart your Server`